# BroadcastReceiver works only after first execution of adb shell

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, notificationmanager, bootcompleted

I tried many different examples, and after some (long) time, I finally managed (almost) to receive logs from BroadcastReceiver, after that notifications (via service). Still, problem persists.

When I install apk, or build it and run it on usb, BroadcastReceiver doesn't receive intent. I tried to manually run application dozen of times, then to restart (power on/off) my phone - nothing. After that, I tried to debug it with adb shell:

> adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -n com.myapp.example/.BootCompletedReceiver

And, voila! It worked. I checked with reboot - it worked! After that, I reinstaled application, and again - didn't work. After I tried with adb shell - again, everything is working. **Seams like it should work, but only after I run adb shell command from above, for the first time.**

I didn't try with AVD (it's too slow on my machine), just with my HTC ONE (I also checked for HTC ONE issues, knowing that it was a problem with some versions of HTC phones - without any help).

This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myapp.example" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppThemeWhiteActionBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeWhite" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    ...
    <receiver android:name=".BootCompletedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".util.AlarmReceiver"/>
    <service android:name=".NotifyingDailyService" >
    </service>
</application>
```

And those are BootCompletedReceiver and NotifyingDailyService (almost same as from many examples here):

```
public class BootCompletedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    Log.w("boot_broadcast_poc", "starting service...");
    context.startService(new Intent(context, NotifyingDailyService.class));
}

}

public class NotifyingDailyService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent pIntent, int flags, int startId) {
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.random_string));
    builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.random_string));
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
    mNotificationManager.notify(12345, builder.build());
    return super.onStartCommand(pIntent, flags, startId);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to restrict Startup Applications in Android. I guess that your application is restricted too. Go to Settings->Personal->Startup Manager. There you can allow or restrict boot_completed broadcast reception.

Comment: Very few android devices have that Startup Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Installation is not sufficient for your app to start listening to the `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast. The application needs to be started once, i.e. your Custom app class or entry Activity needs to be started once for the `BroadcastReceiver` to be able to hear the `BOOT_COMPLETED` system broadcast. This behaviour is by design, for security reasons.

You can read more about it on this [blog](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/07/05/boot-completed-regression.html) by CommonsWare.

Comment: Yup, I know for that issue since Android 3.1. Problem is that I have started application and run almost all activities before every first boot. Just adb shell somehow "force" it to start listening BOOT_COMPLETED.

Comment: I see. Try adding <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> to the receiver in the manifest.